# Javascript method and function

Tags: javascript, scope

As shown below, the `method()` will output `hello,undefined`. What is the scope of the `method()`? Thank you.

```
var obj = {
    name:'Tom',
    sayHello:function() {
        console.log("hello," + this.name);
    }
}

obj.sayHello();

var method = obj.sayHello;
method();
```

output

```
hello,Tom
hello,undefined
```

Answer (score 3):

Because `method` is part of the `window` object, `this` refers to `window`.

Consider this example

```
var name = 'foo';
method();
```

logs...

```
> hello,foo
```

Answer (score 2):

`obj.sayHello()`'s scope is within `obj`. `method` is a global property, so assigning it to the `sayHello` function makes the `sayHello` function look for `this.name` within the global scope.

To understand this, assign a global property of name directly in the script

```
var obj = {
    name:'Tom',
    sayHello:function() {
        console.log("hello," + this.name);
    }
}

obj.sayHello();

//Assign name to the global scope
this.name = "Jerry";
var method = obj.sayHello;

method.call(this); //Calling from the global scope, same as method()

//Then call method from the obj scope
method.call(obj);
```

Answer (score 2):

The scope of `method` is the global `window` object

You'd have to do:

```
method.call(obj);  //instead of method()
```

or

```
var method = obj.sayHello.bind(obj);
```

to achieve the same efect

Info for the `call` method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Info for the `bind` method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

`var method`'s scope is global. it is equals to just define a function

```
var method = function() {
    console.log("hello," + this.name);
}
```